# How to print list with numbers into nth columns or any tabulated format

Tags: python

I wanted to display a list into nth columns and add numbering in every item. So far, the code I have below has the numbering but the output is not divided into 2 columns as I wanted.

```
myList = ["AASD", "ASDASD", "QWEQ", "GFHG", "YUIYU", "NSDF", "LDFS", "QSDAD", "FDRT", "YSLSJ"]

count = 0
for j, i in enumerate(myList):
    count += 1
    if j%2==0:
        print('\n')
    #print(i, end= " ")             # using this, it will be in 2 columns but no numbers
    print ("{} {}".format(count,i)) # using this, with numbers but single column
```

Current Output:

```
1 AASD
2 ASDASD

3 QWEQ
4 GFHG

5 YUIYU
6 NSDF

7 LDFS
8 QSDAD

9 FDRT
10 YSLSJ
```

Needed Output:

```
1. AASD     2. ASDASD 
3. QWEQ     4. GFHG 
5. YUIYU    6. NSDF 
7. LDFS     8. QSDAD 
9. FDRT     10. YSLSJ
```

Comment: You need to print without the carriage return "1. AASD     2. ASDASD "  then carriage return every other entry.

use the end arguemnt such as: print('Hello, World!' , end='')

Comment: `count` and `j` are redundant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for i, item in enumerate(myList, 1):
    print("{:2}. {:<10}".format(i, item), end="")
    if i % 2 == 0:
        print()  # new line
```

Result:

```
 1. AASD       2. ASDASD    
 3. QWEQ       4. GFHG      
 5. YUIYU      6. NSDF      
 7. LDFS       8. QSDAD     
 9. FDRT      10. YSLSJ
```

Answer (score 1):

You were close-- here's a solution with `range` instead, in increments of 2. I also added a bit to handle and odd number of items in `myList`.

```
myList = ["AASD", "ASDASD", "QWEQ", "GFHG", "YUIYU", "NSDF", "LDFS", "QSDAD", "FDRT", "YSLSJ"]

for i in range(0, len(myList), 2):
    # Add a check to see if list length is odd
    if i + 1 < len(myList):
        line = f"{i+1}. {myList[i]:<8} {i+2}. {myList[i+1]}"
    else:
        line = f"{i+1}. {myList[i]}"
    print(line)
```

This returns:

[image]

and if you do `myList = ["AASD", "ASDASD", "QWEQ"]`, it returns this:

[image]

Comment: This would be improved by posting formatted text instead of pictures of output.

Comment: You don't have to "prove" that your answer is correct, others can verify it by reading and using the code you have shown. (And screenshots of console output does not not prove anything either, you might have faked it as easily as formatting text in a text box)

Answer (score 0):

This is a very reasonable place to use [`itertools.batched`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.batched) to iterate over the original list in chunks of two elements each.

```
>>> import itertools
>>> myList = ["AASD", "ASDASD", "QWEQ", "GFHG", "YUIYU", "NSDF", "LDFS", "QSDAD", "FDRT", "YSLSJ"]
>>> itertools.batched(myList, 2)
<itertools.batched object at 0x10b43a620>
>>> list(itertools.batched(myList, 2))
[('AASD', 'ASDASD'), ('QWEQ', 'GFHG'), ('YUIYU', 'NSDF'), ('LDFS', 'QSDAD'), ('FDRT', 'YSLSJ')]
>>> batch_sz = 2
>>> for i, batch in enumerate(itertools.batched(myList, batch_sz)):
...     for j, x in enumerate(batch):
...         start_lbl = i * batch_sz + 1
...         print(f"{start_lbl + j:2}. {x:<10}", end="")
...     print()
... 
 1. AASD       2. ASDASD    
 3. QWEQ       4. GFHG      
 5. YUIYU      6. NSDF      
 7. LDFS       8. QSDAD     
 9. FDRT      10. YSLSJ
```